# Update campo y sumar

Tags: php, sql

Tengo la siguiente base de datos:

| temporada | nombre | cantidadCapitulos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Juego de tronos | 13 |
| 3 | Monk | 34 |

Tengo que realizar un ejercicio mediante php, donde, mediante un formulario, el usuario puede añadir temporadas a la serie que quiera.

El usuario, gracias al formulario, podrá añadir el numero de capítulos y automáticamente, en la fila temporada, se le sumará un 1.

Ejemplo:

Quiero añadir 5 capítulos a la nueva temporada de monk. Automáticamente quedaría así:

| temporada | nombre | cantidadCapitulos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Juego de tronos | 13 |
| 4 | Monk | 39 |

No logro ver como seria el codigo sql. Hago una suma al campo cantidadCapitulos y luego el campo temporada+1?

Como lo puedo plantear?

Gracias

Comment: Por favor, ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que has intentado? Si no podemos ver donde te has equivocado, no podemos ayudarte a corregirlo.

Comment: Realmente no tengo ningún codigo porque no se como afrontarlo. Hago primero el update en sql y luego un if para sumar +1 a temporadas o hay algun update en sql donde pueda añadir 20 capitulos y luego +1 a temporada?

Comment: Te animo a que lo intentes, una idea de como lo podrías resolver ya tenes. Si no te funciona, podes [edit] tu pregunta y agrega el código, explicar que paso y cual es el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente ya tienes la respuesta, un sentencia SQL puede hacer actualizaciones a uno o varios registros con el resultado de operaciones aritméticas básicas (suma, resta, división y multiplicación).

Suponiendo que recibes el valor de los nuevos capítulos como un 5, la consulta podría ser algo como esto en MySql, (utiliza los nombre correctos de los campos)

```
UPDATE series SET capitulos = (capitulos + 5), temporada = (temporada + 1) WHERE nombre = 'Monk';
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Existe alguna forma de poner otra condicion del tipo: Quiero que se haga el update si temporada (de la tabla temporada) no supera temporadas previstas (de la tabla series). Es decir, hacer el update de la temporada siempre que no supere las temporadas previstas. Es possible o ya seria en php?